# Not able to fetch data from json array dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

i have json array

```
JSON.stringify(ar)
```

when i use to dispaly the results in alert like

```
alert(JSON.stringify(ar));
```

it will show as they are. the output in the alert is simple this

> [{"url":"link1","title":"title1"}]

but when i use to transfer its contents into an array of playlist, Like

```
var playlist=[];
playlist=JSON.stringify(ar); alert (JSON.stringify(playlist[1].url));
```

and try to show its results it is giving me the error and giving me undefined

Please help me to sort it out.

Comment: Why are you stringifying everything? Just pass the `ar` object itself!

Comment: this is to be expected, as you're trying to access the *stringified* data as an ordinary array

Comment: Also, your playlist would have only one item then, which you would access via `playlist[0]` - arrays are zero-indexed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to deal with the objects themselves. `JSON.stringify` is only needed to display them in a readable format, when you are outputting the objects or sending them over the wire or so.

```
var ar = [{"url":"link1","title":"title1"}]

alert(ar); // equivalent to alert(ar.toString()), will show [object Object]
alert(JSON.stringify(ar)); // will show [{"url":"link1","title":"title1"}]
console.log(ar); // the proper way to do it, inspect the result in console

var playlist=[];

// then do either
playlist = playlist.concat(ar);
// or
playlist.push.apply(playlist, ar);
// or
playlist.push(ar[0]);
// or
playlist[0] = ar[0];
// or
playlist = ar;
// (which all do a little different things)
// but notice none of them used JSON.stringify!

// now you can
console.log(playlist)
alert(playlist[0].url); // shows link1 - this is what you want
alert(JSON.stringify(playlist[0].url)); // shows "link1"
```

Answer (score 0):

After this

```
var playlist=[];

playlist=JSON.stringify(ar)
```

playlist contain the string so if you want to extract url you need to parse that JSON again

```
alert(JSON.parse(playlist)[1].url);
```

but if you put `[1]` then the array need to have two elements:

```
[{"url":"link1","title":"title1"},{"url":"link1","title":"title1"}]
```

Comment: every thing is fine but 
alert(JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(playlist)[1].url));
gives output as "link1" and i need it without inverted commas Like this
link 1

Comment: @user2838253 Just don't use JSON.strongify then.